# Calling Promise.all throws Promise.all called on non-object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to return promises from a promise and run `Promise.all` like this:

```
updateVideos()
.then(videos => {
     return videos.map(video => updateUrl({ id: video, url: "http://..." }))
})
.then(Promise.all) // throw Promise.all called on non-object
```

How can I use this kind of `Promise.all`. I know `.then(promises => Promise.all(promises))` works. But, just trying to know why that failed.

This happens with Express `res.json` too. The error message is different, but I think the reason is same.

For example:

```
promise().then(res.json) // Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
```

does not work but

```
promise().then(results =>res.json(results))
```

does.

Comment: `Promise.all` uses context (`this`) as a constructor for a new promise it returns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`all` needs to be called with `this` referring to `Promise` (or a subclass), so you'd need:

```
.then(promises => Promise.all(promises))
```

or

```
.then(Promise.all.bind(Promise))
```

It's important because `all` needs to work correctly when inherited in Promise subclasses. For instance, if I do:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
}
```

...then the promise created by `MyPromise.all` should be created by `MyPromise`, not `Promise`. So `all` uses `this`. Example:

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  constructor(...args) {
    console.log("MyPromise constructor called");
    super(...args);
  }
}
console.log("Creating two generic promises");
const p1 = Promise.resolve("a");
const p2 = Promise.resolve("a");
console.log("Using MyPromise.all:");
const allp = MyPromise.all([p1, p2]);
console.log("Using then on the result:");
allp.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Details in [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.all). <sub>(Which I'm going to have to re-read in order to understand why *five* calls to `MyPromise` are made when I call `MyPromise.all` in the above.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the `why`.

Comment: 5 calls because one for creating the returned promise, one for `MyPromise.resolve(p1)`, one for `….then(…)` on that, one for `MyPromise.resolve(p2)`, and one for `….then(…)` on that. Ugh.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks. I figured it was something like that, just didn't have time to dive into it at the mo. :-) (And yeah: Ugh.)

Answer (score 0):

TJ Crowder's response explained why this happens. But if you are looking for a different solution, BluebirdJS (an npm promise library) handles this situation a bit differently. The following code works fine for me.

Using bluebird can also be helpful for dealing with promises that need to be executed and evaluated sequentially. `mapSeries` has been a life-saver for me.

```js
import * as Promise from "bluebird"

// ...

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => arrayOfPromises)
  .then(Promise.all)
```